Embed pdf from storage into view
I want to embed a pdf from storage into a view/iframe. The storage is private and I can't permanently store the files on public folder.
Is there any way to accomplish this? Now the users need to see the pdf directly on page instead of downloading it.
I thought copying the file to public and delete it after being served, it's a valid approach?
Thanks for any guidance!

Maybe you can try using temporary URLs. Check docs here https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/filesystem#temporary-urls
If you need a more robust logic, add to that new endpoint a simple check for user authentication before serving the file.

Try using temporary urls given by laravel like so:
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$url = Storage::temporaryUrl(
    'file.jpg', // Replace with your file.
    now()->addMinutes(5),
    [
        'ResponseContentType' => 'application/octet-stream', // Add any headers as you need.
        'ResponseContentDisposition' => 'attachment; filename=file2.jpg',
    ]
);


So, for ay of you that are seeking information on this.
I created a controller to serve the file, and there, I controller permissions and validations. This controller is also inside of auth middleware.
    // Validate $exam_id
    if (!is_numeric($request->exam_id))
    {
        abort(404);
    }

    // Validate permissions
    if (!$this->validate_whether_the_user_can_check_exam_raw_report($request->exam_id))
    {
        abort(403);
    }

    // Get file from storage
    $file = Storage::disk('exams')->path($request->exam_id.'/raw_ecg.png');

    // Return response with file directly to a new browser tab
    return response()->file($file);

